# Cmake/Ubuntu - Unable to find_package(ZSTD)

Tags: cmake

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.

I have installed zstd by:

```
sudo apt-get install -y zstd
```

Than I installed from the source:

```
~/zstd/build-cmake-debug$ sudo ninja install
[8/9] Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/zstd/zstdTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/zstd/zstdTargets-release.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/zstd/zstdConfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/zstd/zstdConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libzstd.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/zstd.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/zdict.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/zstd_errors.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libzstd.so.1.5.5
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libzstd.so.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libzstd.so
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libzstd.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/zstd
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/zstdcat
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/unzstd
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/zstdgrep
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/zstdless
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/zstd.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/zstdcat.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/unzstd.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/zstdgrep.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/share/man/man1/zstdless.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/zstdmt
```

And here is my prety blank freshly created project CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(ZSTDTest)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/usr/local/lib/cmake/zstd")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
find_package(ZSTD REQUIRED)
add_executable(ZSTDTest main.cpp)
```

And than I see this error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindZstd.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Zstd", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Zstd" with any of
  the following names:

    ZstdConfig.cmake
    zstd-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Zstd" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Zstd_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Zstd"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[Finished]
```

Why CMake is unable to find ZSTD library? Where is the issue and how can I fix it ?

Comment: You need to install **dev** package ([libzstd-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/libzstd-dev) in your case). Exactly dev package contains header files and libraries without so-versions, which can be used when **build** the application against the library. Non-dev packages provides libraries which can be usable for already-built applications only. See e.g. [that question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1071803) on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I already have this installed and yet to no diffrence. `libzstd-dev is already the newest version (1.4.8+dfsg-3build1)`

Comment: Ok. It seems that Ubuntu package for zstd [doesn't provide](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/libzstd-dev/filelist) a config file `zstdConfig.cmake` which could be consumed by `find_package()`. For get that file, you need to build and install zstd project from **sources** (and make sure to build it with CMake from `build/cmake` directory). Actually many Ubuntu packages lack for CMake config files, even when building the corresponding package from sources produces such config file.

Comment: I build it from source. However it installs it kinda localy to the user not to the system. It installs in like /home/user/zstd/lib . Should it be installed system wide? If so how can I install it system wide ?

Comment: In CMake installation prefix is set via `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable: `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<...>`. System-wide prefix is `/usr/local`. Actually, CMake should use system-wide prefix by default, so I am not sure why do you got it installed under `/home/user/zstd`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've installed it on a system level but still Cmake acts really weird, check out this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77157919/cmake-library-not-found-for-lzstd

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have updated the question because I've installed even from the source and gave a location to it and again CMake seems to not be able to find ZSTD. I am really not understanding what is happening here. Any ideas ?

Comment: The name of the package in the error message - `Zstd` - doesn't correspond to the one which is written in the shown code (`ZSTD`). It seems that you actually configure some other code. Also, variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is used only for find `Find*.cmake` scripts. This variable doesn't help in searching for scripts `*config.cmake`. Instead, set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or `Zstd_DIR`, as the error message suggests.

Comment: @UpAndAdam: This question is about fail during the `find_package` itself, and the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77157919/cmake-library-not-found-for-lzstd) is about successfull `find_package` but problems in using its result. So, the questions are definitely different. As far as I understand, the given question is for Linux, and other for MacOS.

Comment: @Tsyvarev fair enough, thats why I checked first i didnt notice that difference, also i posted the totally wrong link above lol. just odd because its the same person about nearly the same thing.