# CMake - library not found for -lZSTD

Tags: c++, cmake

I have compiled ZSTD from the source and I have it installed on system level.

Here is my CMakeLIsts.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Qt for iOS sets MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER automatically since Qt 6.1.
# If you are developing for iOS or macOS you should consider setting an
# explicit, fixed bundle identifier manually though.
if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
    set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.BeastBurstAgent)
endif()


qt_add_executable(BeastBurst_Agent
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        beastburst_agent.h
        beastburst_agent.cpp
        beastburst_agent.ui
        beastburstagent_main.cpp
    )

set_target_properties(BeastBurst_Agent PROPERTIES
        ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
        WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

if(APPLE)
    set_target_properties(BeastBurst_Agent PROPERTIES
            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/BeastBurst.app/Contents/MacOS/
    )
elseif(WIN32)
    set_target_properties(BeastBurst_Agent PROPERTIES
            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/
    )
else() # Assuming Linux
    set_target_properties(BeastBurst_Agent PROPERTIES
            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/
    )
endif()

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    target_compile_definitions(BeastBurst_Agent PRIVATE DEVELOPMENT_ENV)
else()
    target_compile_definitions(BeastBurst_Agent PRIVATE PRODUCTION_ENV)
endif()

target_include_directories(BeastBurst_Agent PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/BBPatcher/)


find_package(ZSTD REQUIRED)

if(ZSTD_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Found in Agent zstd: ${ZSTD_VERSION}")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "zstd not found")
endif()

target_link_libraries(BeastBurst_Agent PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Network ${BZIP2_LIBRARIES} ZSTD   BBPatcher HDiffPatch)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(BeastBurst_Agent)
endif()
```

When I run CMake I can clearly see that CMake finds zstd because I see this output:

-- Found in Agent zstd: 1.5.5

However when I try to build BeastBurst_Agent I get this error:

```
[ 97%] Linking CXX executable ../BeastBurst.app/Contents/MacOS/BeastBurst_Agent.app/Contents/MacOS/BeastBurst_Agent
ld: library not found for -lZSTD
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [BeastBurst.app/Contents/MacOS/BeastBurst_Agent.app/Contents/MacOS/BeastBurst_Agent] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Agent/CMakeFiles/BeastBurst_Agent.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Agent/CMakeFiles/BeastBurst_Agent.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [BeastBurst_Agent] Error 2
```

Why it does not want to link it? What can be the issue and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Could be capitalization. Does macOS have case sensitive filesystems like linux? If that is the case `ZSTD` should be `zstd`

Comment: `find_package` doesn't change the library directories, you need to use the outputs of the `find_package` process, either the variables it defines or preferably the target

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call for `find_package(zstd)` provides **targets** [libzstd_shared](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/blob/dev/build/cmake/lib/CMakeLists.txt#L121) and [libzstd_static](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/blob/dev/build/cmake/lib/CMakeLists.txt#L134) which are [prefixed](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/blob/dev/build/cmake/CMakeLists.txt#L205) with `zstd::`.

That is, you need to use `zstd::libzstd_shared` for link with the shared ZSTD library, or `zstd::libzstd_static` for link with the static one.